# R: Deleting rows but skip NA

Tags: r, na

with this code i pretend to delete the rows in the `a` column  which have the word `"TRUE"`.

```
DATA2 <- DATA[!DATA$a == "TRUE”]
```

However, I have `"TRUE"`, `"FALSE"` and `"NA"`. When I run this code R deletes the NA's as well. How can i skip this and only delete the rows with a "TRUE"?

I've already tried this one, but without success...

```
DATA2 <- DATA[!DATA$a=='TRUE',na.rm= FALSE]
```

Error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(DATA, !DATA$a == "TRUE",  : 
  unused argument (na.rm = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi Ana: Can you tell us if your column is a factor variable or boolean? you should be able to figure it out by doing `class(NIRDATA$gh_fat_hy_outlier)`

Comment: A reproducible example would help a lot, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for some help.

Comment: Hi, 
It's a "character".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created some reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1:15), 
  col2=rep(c("TRUE","FALSE", "NA"),5), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Using base R, you can do this:

```
df2 <- df[df$col2 == "NA" | !df$col2 == "TRUE", ]
```

In dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% filter(col2 == "NA" | !col2 == "TRUE" )
```

Output:

```
> df2
   col1  col2
2     2 FALSE
3     3    NA
5     5 FALSE
6     6    NA
8     8 FALSE
9     9    NA
11   11 FALSE
12   12    NA
14   14 FALSE
15   15    NA
```

// Edit: 
changed `NA` values to Strings (`"NA"`) as supplied in the question.

// Note:

If you want to convert `"TRUE"` to `TRUE`, `"FALSE"` to `FALSE` and `"NA"` to `NA`, you can do this:

```
df_bool <- data.frame(
  col1 = df$col1, 
  col2 = as.logical(df$col2)
)
```

Since `df_bool$col2` will return real logical values instead of Strings looking like logical values, it can be used within `if` itself, without having to use `==` for `TRUE` and `FALSE` values:

```
df2 <- df_bool[!df_bool$col2 | is.na(df_bool$col2), ]
```

Comment: I actually prefer your answer, it is more explicit about what it is doing. My suggestion takes a little more time to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm a beginner, code is completely new for me!
It solved my problem :)

Comment: No problem @AnaRaquel, glad I could help! :)

Comment: Apparently the error persists!

When i try with the solution that @kaetschap wrote, it works, but not with my data...

I tried with this but the TRUES, FALSES and NA's are still there...

    df2 <- df1[is.na(df1$outlier) | !df1$outlier == "TRUE", ]

all columns are "characters' ...

Why is it not working? Can you help me, pelase?I'm sorry to bothering you again with the same question..

Comment: could it be that your column is `"NA"`, not `NA`? Then is.na(col2) would always be `FALSE`, since your `NA` values are not actually `NA`, but Strings. If that is the case, you can do this: `df2 <- df %>% filter(col2 == "NA") | !col2 == "TRUE" )`. I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First create some example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(x = runif(10), 
                y = runif(10), 
                z = sample(c('TRUE', 'FALSE', NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # Force to character, and not factor
```

The trick I use here is to replace the `NA` with `"FALSE"` inside the filter:

```
df[!ifelse(is.na(df$z), 'FALSE', df$z) == 'TRUE',]
            x         y     z
1  0.26550866 0.2059746  <NA>
3  0.57285336 0.6870228 FALSE
6  0.89838968 0.4976992 FALSE
8  0.66079779 0.9919061 FALSE
9  0.62911404 0.3800352  <NA>
10 0.06178627 0.7774452 FALSE
```

I really like the `dplyr` style of programming:

```
df %>% filter(ifelse(is.na(z), 'FALSE', z) != 'TRUE')
           x         y     z
1 0.26550866 0.2059746  <NA>
2 0.57285336 0.6870228 FALSE
3 0.89838968 0.4976992 FALSE
4 0.66079779 0.9919061 FALSE
5 0.62911404 0.3800352  <NA>
6 0.06178627 0.7774452 FALSE
```